# SQL Server, Calling stored procedure per column with specific field value

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have a table `BounceStatistics` with the columns: `Email_Address`,`Bounces`,`Status`,`Week`,`Year`

i have a stored procedure named `GetStatus` with the following parameters`Email_address`,`Week`,`Year`.
The procedure fills the status column of the BounceStatistics table collected out of another set of tables.

My Question:
How do i run the stored procedure for each record in `BounceStatistics` where the value is currently `null`? 
(i read that i should avoid loops but i think its the only way)

I would love to learn better practises as well, so any tips on what i should do in the future instead of what i show right now would be welcome.

Comment: The `Status` value is null, sorry for not mentioning that earlier. The issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the SP was written specifically to update (or insert?) a single row.
This in itself is problematic.

Think about rewriting it as a function and calling it as part of an UPDATE statement.

And yes, loops should be avoided (and usual can be avoided) ;-)

Comment: If the `BounceStatistics ` table has 10 rows, and 8 of these 10 rows are empty at the status column (null) how should i go about this?

Comment: It's difficult to give you an exact answer without more details (eg: what the SP does, table structure etc.).

Comment: Loops should and have been avoided :-). I updated the stored procedure that fills the `BounceStatistics` table so it also generates the `status` for each record it fills on insert.